# Angular 6- How can I make form fields only appear if a user inputs a specific value?

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have an Angular form with a dropdown list, and at the the end of the list is the option 'Other'. If a user selects other, I would like a new field to appear allowing them to input another option.

I tried using ngModel, but learned you can't include that within an *ngIf statement, but I think I might be on the right track.

```
<form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" >
       <tr>
           <td>
                <p>Location Type :</p>
           </td>
           <td> <select class="col-md-12 form-control"[(ngModel)]="newmp.locationType" name="locationType">
                   <option value="Outfall">Outfall</option>
                   <option value="Tide Gate">Tide Gate</option>
                   <option value="Upstream">Upstream Pipe</option>
                   <option value="Vault">Vault</option>
                   <option value="Other">Other</option></select>
           </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr *ngIf="locationType == Other">
           <td class="left_td">
                 <p>Other (locationType) :</p>
           </td>
           <td> 
                    <input type="text" name="locationTypeOther"  placeholder="Other (Location Type) "class="col-md-12 form-control" [(ngModel)]="newmp.locationTypeOther" />
           </td>
       </tr> 
</form>
```

In my component I have:

```
newmp = {
        "locationType": "",
        "locationTypeOther": ""
        }
```

The way I have it now, the 'locationTypeOther" field will appear upon page load, even before a user selects an option. What might I be missing? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, but what field is supposed to appear when you select `other`? Are you referring to the `<input>` within the second `<tr>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<tr *ngIf="locationType == Other">
```

It should be

```
<tr *ngIf="newmp.locationType == 'Other'">
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Looks like I needed that model reference.